# Kill a process with shell/batch script based on Private Working Set Memory value

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I would like to know how can I adjust the following code, to kill a specific process (there are multiple processes with the same name), based on its Private Working Set memory usage.

```
Get-Process myPROCESSNAME -ea 0 | where { $_.PM -le 10MB } | foreach {
    $Path = $_.Path
    if ($Path) {
        Stop-Process $_ -Force
    }
}
```

When I open Task Manager, I can clearly see that the processes that I want to automatically kill are using around 4 MB of RAM, while the ones that I don't want to kill use more than 20MB of RAM.

I've fiddled around with a C# console application, but I was not really able to get the same Memory reading, that I can see thru Task Manager.
Then I realised that Task Manager displays the Private Working Set memory (by default), so that's what I need to filter out the bad processes.

Can this be achieved via a batch/PowerShell script?

Comment: The `PM` property is not 'Private Working Set' - it is 'Paged Memory'.  You probably want something like the 'WorkingSet' (`WS`), `'PrivateMemorySize` or `PrivateMemorySize64` instead

Answer (score 1):

In batch you can do it as well.:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('tasklist /FI "memusage lt 10000" ^|findstr /i "myPROCESSNAME"') do echo taskkill /PID %%i
```

This will do a tasklist and get processes with memory usage `l`ess `t`han 10000kb (10mb).

We then simply use findstr to fiter on your process (myPROCESSNAME) and then kill the process by its `PID`.

**Note** I added `echo` after do. This is for testing purpose so you can at least see what the command will do without *actually* perfoming the task. Once you are happy with the result, remove `echo` to actually perform the `taskkill` command.

I suggest you read up on some help for the above given commands:

- `for /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `taskkill /?`

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want the `Memory (Private Working Set)` you could get that information using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) with `Get-WmiObject`:

```ps1
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process -Property IDProcess,Name,WorkingSetPrivate | `
    Where-Object { $_.Name -Eq 'myPROCESSNAME' -And $_.WorkingSetPrivate -Lt 5242880 } | `
    ForEach-Object { ( Get-Process -Id $_.IDProcess ).CloseMainWindow() }
```

Please note that you may need to check what your `Name` value is, *it is usually the name of the executatble without its `.exe` extension*. In this example, I have used `5MB` *(i.e. 5242880 bytes)* as the minimum size to keep open. Additionally, I have for the purpose of this example used the 'friendly' `CloseMainWindow` instruction for closing the process, depending upon your process, you may need to change that to something more appropriate.

Comment: Will this work if I have processes with the EXACT same name? I somehow can't get your code to work

Comment: @drmdrm, I have no intention of playing guessing games, I answered your question the best I could, based on your limited information. If you want further advice from me, you will need to supply your exact code complete with the actual process name, and fully explain the issues you're having. Please note however, that if your additional information markedly changes your question, I will not answer it here, _you'll need to create a new question_.